# Обработчик элемента img, добавляемого при загрузке страницы

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый день! Помогите новичку в js с вопросом. Есть код:

```
$( window ).ready( function() {
    $.post("http://album/script.php", {pic: true}, function(data) {
        var arr = data.split(' ');
        if (arr.length == 0) return;
        if (arr.length % 2 == 0) 
            var i = (arr.length / 2) - 1;
        else 
            var i = Math.floor(arr.length / 2);

        if(!(i==0)) arr = arr.slice(i-1, i+2);
        for (i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            var imgSmall = new Image();
            var imgBig = new Image();

            if (i == (Math.floor(arr.length / 2))) {
                $(imgBig).addClass("active");
                $(imgSmall).addClass("active");
            }
            $(imgBig).attr("src", "../img/" + arr[i]);
            $(imgSmall).attr("src", "../imgSmall/" + arr[i]);
            $(".imgBig").append(imgBig);
            $(".smallFlow").append(imgSmall);
        }   

    }); 

    $(".smallFlow img").click(function() {
        $(".smallFlow .active).toggleClass("active");
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
    }); 
});
```

При загрузке окна идет запрос изображений через ajax , вывод их на страницу, а при нажатии на эти изображения должен добавляться/удаляться класс active.
Однако обработчик по нажатию мыши не срабатывает.
Подозреваю, что причиной является то, что изображения на страницу добавляются динамически, однако что с этим делать - непонятно.
Подскажите, как решить проблему!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Однако обработчик по нажатию мыши не срабатывает.

В момент добавления обработчика события `click` элемент `.smallFlow img` не существует в DOM дереве.

Есть два варианта решения вашей проблемы:

1. Регистрировать событие на элемент после того, как он появится в DOM дереве:

   ```
   $.post("http://album/script.php", { pic: true }, function(data) {
       // добавить в конце
       $(".smallFlow img").click(function() {
           $(".smallFlow .active").toggleClass("active");
               $(this).toggleClass("active");
       });
   });
   ```
2. Слушать события динамически:

   ```
   $(document).on('click', '.smallFlow img', function() {
       $(".smallFlow .active").toggleClass("active");
       $(this).toggleClass("active");
   });
   ```

Для версии jQuery < 1.7:

```
$('.smallFlow img').live(function() {
    $(".smallFlow .active").toggleClass("active");
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!  А проясните, пожалуйста, еще такую деталь. Мне не совсем понятно, почему все-таки img не был в DOM до обработчика, ведь он добавлялся внутри .post(), который в коде как раз стоял перед click()

Comment: Ajax запросы работают асинхронно, соответственно запрос еще не завершился, а вызов метода click уже отработал и элементы .smallFlow img в тот момент отсутствовали.

Comment: Откройте для себя отладку JavaScript: https://learn.javascript.ru/debugging-chrome

Answer (score -1):

Ход Вашей догадки верный. Вместо:

```
.click(function() {
```

надо вставить:

```
.live( "click", function() {
```

live будет обрабатывать динамические события.

Comment: смотря в какой версии `jquery` В `1.11` будет ошибка. Потому, что начиная с версии `1.7` метод устарел и там его нет

Comment: Предлагать метод `.live()`, который был "deprecated" в версии 1.7 и "removed" в версии 1.9 - плохая затея.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский "там его нет" - в 1.7 он по-прежнему был.

Comment: @Regent я имел в виду что в 1.7 устарел, а в 1.11 его уже нет) Предложение, видимо, плохо построил